# network connection fails when iPhone is locked

Tags: ios, iphone, error-handling, network-connection

i developed an app that makes a http request (async call) when server responses at that time if iPhone is locked. network connection fails, i am getting an error code -1005 "network connection fail". how can i maintain network connection when phone is locked and allow the app to receive response when phone is unlocked again or in background. Also app crashes when user kills app when receiving response.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [Background Execution and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html). It allows your app to function up to about 10 minutes while in background.

Here's sample code from the doc:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you.
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```

Comment: That probably isn't the best background mode to use. You are limited to a few minutes execution time. Background fetch or VoIP modes may be more appropriate depending on the OPs app